# Maximizing the value of an equation given a constraint in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, data-science

There are four variables 
`(S1, S2, S3, S4)` 
with the constraint 
`(S1+S2+S3+S4=100)`. 
There are four given constants `(C1, C2, C3, C4)`. I want to maximize the value of `(S1/C1 + S2/C2 + S3/C3 + S4/C4)`.  Here is my code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

S0 = [25, 25, 25, 25]
C = [89415,8991,10944,15164]

def objective(S, C):
    total = 0
    for index in range(4):
        total = total + S[index]/C[index]        
    return -total

def constraint(S):
    return (100 - S[0] - S[1] - S[2] - S[3])

b = (0.0, 100.0)
boundaries = (b,b,b,b)
con = ({'type':'eq', 'fun':constraint})

solution = minimize(objective,S0,args=(C),method='SLSQP',bounds=boundaries,constraints=con)

print (solution)
```

My code is simply returning the initial guess for S as the final result

`fun: -0.0069931517268763755
     jac: array([-1.11838453e-05, -1.11222384e-04, -9.13742697e-05, -6.59456709e-05])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([25., 25., 25., 25.])`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: any ideas anyone? I am stuck at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the differences in the output values of your functions are within the default tolerance for the optimizer to stop optimizing your function between iterations. Setting your tolerance to a smaller value like `1e-12` helps with this:

```
solution = minimize(objective,S0,args=(C),method='SLSQP',bounds=boundaries,constraints=con, tol=1e-12)
```

Result:

```
   fun: -0.01112223334445557
     jac: array([ -1.11837871e-05,  -1.11222267e-04,  -9.13742697e-05,
        -6.59456709e-05])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 192
     nit: 32
    njev: 32
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+02,   3.01980663e-14,
         0.00000000e+00])
```

which is approximately equal to the absolute maximum solution [0,100,0,0].